# Making a chessboard and i'm getting an IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: list, python-3.5, index-error

Title
I'm currently trying to get a user to input a chessboard using dashes (-) and the letters corresponding to the pieces. But the list isn't saving properly. Here's the code that's screwing up.

```
def make_a_chessboard():
 chessboard = []

 possible_char = ["-","K","k","Q","q","R","r","N","n","B","b","P","p"]
 rows = 8
 cols = 8
 for r in range(rows):
     user_input = input("")
     while len(user_input) != 8:
         print("That is not the correct length. Please try again.")
         user_input = input("")
 for i in range(len(user_input)):
     flag1 = False
     while flag1 == False:
         if user_input[i] not in possible_char:
             print("One of the characters used is not supported. Please try again.")
             user_input = input("")
         else:
             for c in range(cols):

                 chessboard[r][c].append(user_input[c])
             flag1 = True
 return(chessboard)
```

This gives me the IndexError: list index out of range error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line of code is producing the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a81.py", line 73, in <module>
    main()
  File "a81.py", line 69, in main
    user_chessboard = make_a_chessboard()
  File "a81.py", line 30, in make_a_chessboard
    chessboard[r][c].append(user_input[c])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Could you include a copy of the input you're trying as well?

Comment: I'll enter in 8 lines of code with dashes or letters. The input would just be one line of dashes like "--------" or "--k-K-Q-"

Comment: Ohh, I see. I was expecting a list assignment error, but because append is a method you're getting the list index out of range.

it's because chessboard[r] doesn't exit, and therefore chessboard[r][c] never can.

Comment: Ohhh okay I see my code was missing an indent, so i indented everything below "for r in range(rows)", but I still get the error

Comment: There's a few points of error, but the general layout of your code is a bit hard to follow, so I've posted a gently refactored solution below. If you run it and it doesn't work, just let me know and I'll try to tidy it up. Not able to test it atm

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a bit of a restructure of the code so you test the validity once and completely of your input for each row, and then we can build the list of each position on a particular row, and append this to the chessboard list. The below is totally untested, so if there's syntax errors let me know and I'll edit it up.

```
 def is_valid_row(user_in):
    possible_char = ["-","K","k","Q","q","R","r","N","n","B","b","P","p"]
    if len(user_in) != 8:
        print("Please enter a string of 8 characters")
        return False
    for each_char in user_in:
        if each_char not in possible_char:
            print("You have entered illegal char {}".format(each_char))
            return False
    # Neither of those other two have returned false
    # so we're good to assume it's valid
    return True

 def make_a_chessboard():
     chessboard = []
     rows = 8

     # Process each row (you do this line by line, right?)
     for r in range(rows):
        user_input = input("")
        while not is_valid_row(user_input):
             user_input = input("")

        # We now have valid input (or we're stuck in while-loop-hell)
        # break the input into a list (of 8 valid chars)
        each_row = [x for x in user_input]

        # Now append it to chessboard
        chessboard.append(each_row)


    return(chessboard)
```